# HTMLEncode and HTMLDecode not working when data is bound to asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html-entities, html-encode

I have a weird observation with respect to `HttpUtility.HTMLEncode` and `HttpUtility.HTMLDecode` when encoded data is bound to a grid and later decoded on `rowdatabound` event. Here is some code for background.

**Data is Encoded and bound to the grid view** - Observe usage of `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`

```
for (var index = 0; index < dtData.Rows.Count; index++)
{
    DataRow row = dtData.Rows[index];
    row.ItemArray = row.ItemArray.Select(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode).ToArray<object>();
}
DataTable dtEncodedData = dtData;

gview.DataSource = dtEncodedData;
gview.DataBind();
gview.Visible = true;
```

When I decode the inputted data on RowDataBound event I do not get the same value back from encoded data. It seems gridview is also applying it's encoding on top of what I am doing so `HTMLDecode` doesn't give what I am looking for?

```
protected void gview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
        }
}
```

---

Input Data - `Single Quote '` 
After Encoding - `Single Quote &#39;` 
decodedText - `Single Quote &#39` - Observe **NOT** same as Input Data 
Value of `e.Row.Cells[i].Text` on `RowDataBound` event is captured as `Single Quote &amp;#39` which is messing up my decode I do not get `Single Quote '` string back.

Should I find a way to stop gridview to encode the data? Insights would be appreciated.

Comment: I tend to just start using templated columns - standard asp.net controls, and most if not all of the issue goes away. The problem with using default (auto generated columns), is they are rendering as table cells, and thus for a empty cell and what not, it will produce say a &nbsp. In the vast majority of cases, we just don't care. but, it can matter. And for a layout, I tend to find that a listview is better WHEN you start wanting to add a lot of custom controls to the grid view. Since I am suggesting to use asp.net controls for all the columns, then the case for LV is even greater.

Comment: I can not change the way gridview is set up with auto-generated columns as different types of data(with varying columns) can be bound to the same grid. Is there a work around to circumvent the issue I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Decode, this one is i'm using in gridview with autogenerate columns true. My .net framework is 4.6

> What is you project framework version>
> Try to keep above 4.0

```
e.Row.Cells[i].Text = Context.Server.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToString());
```

Check this fiddle : [https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uppzxi][1]

As per your inputs its working fine.

Find out where the ";" is missing in the encoding ? And post the code sample .

Comment: Let me check sometime today, did you bind the encoded datatable to gridview first then tried to decode it on RowDatabound event?

Comment: yes, first binded the datatable and on rowdatabound i did the decode part, you post you raw datatable with exact data.